# Terrible cold launch performance of app; possible fix?

Tags: java, android, performance, runtime

My app takes `12MB` of size, however during the cold start of the app, it takes around **40 SECONDS** to load the launcher Activity. I did a traceview to see what's happening inside, and here's what I obtained:

[image]

And once I swept deep through all the methods, here's some that took high time:

1) `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke`
[image]

2) `com.android.internal.os.Zygoteinit.main`
[image]

3) `android.os.Looper.loop()`
[image]

4) `android.app.ActivityThread.main`
[image]

I searched for these methods, however found no result in resolving the launch time performance of the app. What's potentially causing this wide delay, any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT-1**

This is what the APK analyzer provides:
[image]

**PS:**

> I didn't find a way to upload the traceview as a `log`, hence had to
>   upload the images of the same.

Comment: @ArpanSharma I've added apk analyzer screen shot

Comment: try disabling instant run and then run the application.Instant run is known for delay in the launch as it takes some time for itself

Comment: http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Comment: @ArpanSharma I am already following that way for a splash!

Comment: Might be worth enabling StrictMode: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html
You could be doing some blocking IO on the MainThread (without realising)